# Should a pan of brownies really be called "brownies" if uncut and in one piece?

Tags: word-choice

I have never heard anyone call a pan of brownies anything other than a "pan of brownies".

Thinking about this, I realized that there is nothing plural about a pan of brownies.  Is it just that everyone assumes it will be cut and refers to it as such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I don't see anything wrong with this. It's multiple brownies, but they're just not cut yet. Another similar situation is with cocktails; you might say "I made mojitos!" even though they're all together in a pitcher.

Comment: Make 'em whiskey sours and I'll join you.  Can't stand mint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "a brownie" is "the amount of cooked brownie dough that you personally consider one serving."  So you might slice your pan of brownies into 25 brownies, or 16, or 9, or 4, or 2, or just slide the whole thing onto your plate and eat one enormous brownie. (Please don't.)

As long as it's still in the pan, it's a pan of brownies.  Why am I suddenly hungry?

Comment: could be the whiskey sours.